# In java with DB2 parallel process: I got Deadlock Exception :DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=2, DRIVER=3.59.81

Tags: java, db2

How to reproduce this issue in DB2? I already tried the java with oracle multi process but now tried same approach in DB2 with java. I need to reproduce this.

Comment: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P173414

Answer (score 0):

You would need two test tables

```
CREATE TABLE T1 ( c INT);
CREATE TABLE T2 ( c INT);
```

insert some dummy values in each of then force a deadlock with two threads where transaction-enabled connections  (autocommit=false);

thread 1:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO T2 SELECT * FROM T1");
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

thread 2:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO T1 SELECT * FROM T2");
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To replay for me question Mr.Stavr00 and Mr.Opal

I am using parallel processing ,which means i will start all process at the time using processBuilder concept on java.And also i need to run particular target time for 3 million records.